# Ubuntu Desktop versions other than Jammy that run on VMware Fusion Tech Preview on Apple Silicon?

Tags: vmware, apple

I'm having a hard time finding any version of Ubuntu Desktop aarch64 other than Jammy daily builds that run on the VMware Fusion Tech Preview for Apple Silicon. The Jammy builds work with a few issues. Server builds from 20.04 on seems to work OK, but it's a pain to have to install all the graphical components to get the equivalent of a desktop release.

As an example, released Focal aarch64 builds work fine. The only Desktop builds I've been able to find are daily builds, but those will not boot, regardless of what I try with manipulating kernel arguments.

Any hints or am I relegated to using Ubuntu Server for releases other than Jammy?

Comment: All versions should work... Maybe there is a limit to the memory storage since it is a **preview** I am pretty sure that the daily builds have smaller memory than the LTS versions. This question also isn't an official Ubuntu thing and is an issue related to VMware Fusion Tech Preview. Try posting on another Stack on Stack Exchange?

Comment: @Jeff, the daily Jammy Desktop builds work OK, as well as other Linux distros both server and desktop. It's not like I'm constraining the guest - 4GB and 2 vCPU have been plenty to run other distro's fully functional desktop releases. Canonical has their daily builds of arm64, but for some reason decides not to make a released Desktop of other than x86_64? - when they've obviously already built it.